# How to find the minimum and maximum of $\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j$ subject to a constraint?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

We have a symmetric matrix $A$ which entries are $a_{ij}$. Also, there is a function $f(x) = \frac{\sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$ definded everywhere in $R^n$ except at the origin. I need to obtain maximum and minimum values of $f(x)$ expressed via eigenvalues of matrix $A$. In order to do that we are provided with the following system:
$$ \begin{cases} \sum_{i,j=1}^n a_{ij}x_ix_j \to max/min \\ s.t. \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = 1 \end{cases} $$ As far as I understand the best and the only reasonable thing that can be done here is Lagrangian method but undetermined coefficients $a_{ij}$ are really confusing.

Comment: Hint: change the basis to the eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, we want to minimize $f(x)=x^T A x$ (which is a compact notation of your sum) over the unit sphere $g^{-1}(0)$ where $g(x)=x^Tx-1$. The Lagrangian becomes
$$\nabla L(x)=2Ax-\lambda\cdot2x=2(A-\lambda I)x$$
To see why explicitly, note
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}x^TAx = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \sum_{k,\ell=1}^na_{k\ell}x_k x_{\ell} = \sum_{j\neq i}a_{ij} x_j + a_{ji} x_j + 2a_{ii}x_i = 2 \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} x_j = (2Ax)_i$$
To to compute $\nabla g$ plug in $A=I$.

Overall, the critical points are eigenvectors of $A$, and the corrosponding $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues. At each point $x_i$, we have $f(x_i)=x_i^T \cdot \lambda x_i = \lambda_i$. The method ensures us that if there is a maxima and minima (which exist due to Weierstrass' theorem), it is obtained in one of the solutions $x_i$s. thus the global maxima is $\max_{\mathbb S^{n-1}} f = \max_i \lambda_i$ and similarly the minima is $\min_i \lambda_i$.