# Computing minimum eigenvalue as an optimization problem

Tags: matrices, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let ${Q} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be a real symmetric matrix and $p \geq 0$. How can I show that $\min_\limits{y^{\text{T}}y = p}y^{\text{T}}Qy = p \cdot \lambda_{\min}(Q)$ without using the $\min-\max$ theorem? My approach was to use the lagrangian leading to
$$
\mathcal{L}(y,\mu) = y^{\text{T}}Qy + \mu(y^{\text{T}}y - p).
$$
The KKT-conditions are

1. $\nabla_{y}\mathcal{L}(y,\mu) = 0$ $\iff$ $y = (Q + \text{diag}(\mu))^{-1}$
2. $y^{\text{T}}y - p = 0$

I think this would not lead to a solution. Hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 2):

I think there was a mistake when you worked out (1), or I'm just not sure of the notation because the right hand side seems like a matrix. The gradient is using [this similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3590046/how-to-find-the-minimum-and-maximum-of-sum-i-j-1n-a-ijx-ix-j-subject-to/3590308#3590308)
$$\nabla_y \mathcal{L}= (Q+Q^T)y + \mu \cdot 2y = 2(Qy+\mu y)$$
So for this to be zero, $-\mu$ must be an eigenvalue of $Q$ with eigenvector $y_i$. Meaning our critical points are $y_1,\dots,y_n$. For each one the function achieves a value of
$$y_i^T Q y_i=y_i^T \cdot \lambda_i y_i = \lambda_i \|y_i\|_2^2=\lambda_ip$$
where we used the constraint $y^Ty=p$. Out of all these critial points, $\lambda_{\text{min}}$ gives the minima.

Comment: How you can be sure that the corresponding eigenvectors satisfy the constraint $y^{\text{T}}y = p$?

Comment: Well, an "eigenvector" is not a unique vector rather a 1 dimensional subspace. Because if $v$ is an eigenvector then so is $2v,3v,\pi v$ and so on.. So when I substitute in the constraint, I get that $y_i$ the eigenvector in the problem has to be of norm $\sqrt{p}$.